# Creating a share/reusable angular form group component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a reusable form component which accepts id, then load everything in the reusable form component.

Parent (app.component.html)

```
<app-shared-form [id]="selectedId"></app-shared-form>
```

Parent (app.component.ts)

```
selectedId: number = 1;
```

Share component (shared-form.component.html)

```
<form [formGroup]="objectForm">

    <input [formControl]="objectForm.controls['name']" type="text">

</form>
```

Share component (shared-form.component.ts)

```
export class SharedFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() objectId: number;
    objectForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private someSerivce: SomeService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.newObjectForm();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loadObject();
    }

    loadObject() {
      this.someService.getObject(this.objectId).subscribe(response => {
        this.object = response;
        this.objectForm.patchValue(this.object);
      })
    }

    newObjectForm() {
      this.objectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        name: []
      });
    }

}
```

I get error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`, but when I `console.log(this.objectForm)` the `this.objectForm.controls['name']` and value is avaible.

I am not sharing one FormGroup across parent-child. Any idea why?

Comment: <input formControlName="name" type="text">

Answer (score 0):

The `objectForm` won't be available as soon as the shared component is initialized. Therefore in template you need to check whether the `objectForm` is initialized. The value of formGroup will be `undefined` until it is initialized.

```
<form *ngIf="objectForm" [formGroup]="objectForm">
  <input [formControl]="objectForm.controls['name']" type="text">
</form>
```

Also, you can use formControlName instead of directly using the formControl.

```
<form *ngIf="objectForm" [formGroup]="objectForm">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text">
</form>
```